# How can I edit the text after I rendered after I created a video from it?

Tags: animation, edit-mode, text-object

Basically I am new to this and I want to know how can I reuse the same project for multiple intro videos.
My requirement is that I have 2 YouTube channels and I want to reuse the same project that I created for my first channel and I am unable to find a way to change the text for my next channel.

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4_0nNZSWdw and created video.

Now I want to reuse my work and wanna just change the name.
How can I do that?

- My First Channel
  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCae29wGJJIbNbEf2H65-3Pg
- My Second Channel https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCevruQYC_rtYjx7YyMWsxJA
- Blend file : https://openload.co/f/Df89pL2R0hA/fact.blend

Comment: We are not gonna watch a full tutorial just to figure out what you want to do. Please provide screenshots **and** a description of what you currently have or you want to achieve or a link to the Blend file if you want any real help. Generally if you want to change text you only have to edit the text object and change the inserted content string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this tutorial, the text object is converted into a mesh, and this is a point of no return, you cannot edit the text as text anymore. You will have to create the text again and convert it again.

You could theoretically write a script that does all of the steps in the tutorial, and then all you have to do is change the script input and re-run it.